Where to find callee smart contract address?
I am working on smart contract analysis and focusing on smart contract interaction. My goal is to avoid executing the contracts and I wanted to know if it is possible to get the address of a called smart contract directly from the binary file.
The address of the called contract is supposed to be stored in the evm storage. If it is hardcoded and stored there is it done during the constructor part or in the run time part of the binary?
Thank you for your help

Can you please explain your question in more detail?
